# Unable to display data in recycler view from room db

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Getting error at NewActivity, as getting error while adding the data in array list and loading it to recycler view. Iam working on a project where I have to load Room data in recycler view. I am getting an error in for loop .. tried using foreach still getting tge same error. Error is showing while using add method to load a data from list to arraylist

```
package com.app.mycontacts;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;

import com.app.mycontacts.AddContactActivity.AddContactActivity;
import com.app.mycontacts.Data.ContactDetails;
import com.app.mycontacts.Data.ContactRepository;
import com.app.mycontacts.Data.MyAdapterClass;
import com.app.mycontacts.R;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class NewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    ArrayList<ContactDetails> contactarrayList;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView= findViewById(R.id.reyclerview);

        new LoadDataTask().execute();
    }


    class LoadDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

        ContactRepository contactRepository;
        List<ContactDetails> contactList1;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            contactRepository = new ContactRepository(getApplicationContext());
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            contactList1=contactRepository.getContactsDetails();
            contactarrayList= new ArrayList<ContactDetails>();

            for(int i=0; i<=contactList1.size();i++){

                contactarrayList.add(contactList1.get(i));
               
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            super.onPostExecute(unused);

            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(NewActivity.this));

            MyAdapterClass myAdapterClass= new MyAdapterClass(NewActivity.this,contactarrayList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapterClass);
        }
    }

}
```

Tried debugging the code, app is getting crash at the above stage.. Expecting to display the data inserted at room db.

Comment: What is the error?...

Comment: App is getting crash at NewActivity and there is no data in recycler view..in logcat i can see error at LoadDataTask and contactarray.add(contactList.get(i))

Comment: Yes, but what does the error say.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.app.mycontacts.NewActivity$LoadDataTask.doInBackground(NewActivity.java:65)
        at com.app.mycontacts.NewActivity$LoadDataTask.doInBackground(NewActivity.java:46)

Comment: put this ContactRepository contactRepository in global not inside asyncTask.
contactRepository = new ContactRepository(getApplicationContext()); this in onCreate.

Comment: now there is an error at            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(NewActivity.this));

Answer (score 1):

You are indexing wrong in the loop.

The size of the list is 4 but Java indexes from 0. So if you have 4 elements it goes [0], [1], [2], [3]

```
for(int i=0; i<=contactList1.size();i++){
    contactarrayList.add(contactList1.get(i));       
}
```

What you are doing is reaching for the fifth element - `[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]`.

This will work:

```
for(int i=0; i < contactList1.size();i++){
    contactarrayList.add(contactList1.get(i));       
}
```

But you don't need to iterate it, you should be able to just call `.addAll`.

```
contactarrayList.addAll(contactList1);
```

Comment: correct @TheLibrarain..